# Tamanho atual TextBlock runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

Galera, estou com uma dúvida que é a seguinte. Eu estou criando uma TextBlock em tempo de execução com o seguinte código:

```
TextBlock txtMensagem = new TextBlock();
txtMensagem.Text = texto.Trim();
txtMensagem.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
txtMensagem.Height = Double.NaN;
txtMensagem.Width = Double.NaN;
txtMensagem.MinWidth = 200;
txtMensagem.MaxWidth = 500;
txtMensagem.FontSize = 16;
txtMensagem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
txtMensagem.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
txtMensagem.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
txtMensagem.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
txtMensagem.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
txtMensagem.Margin = new Thickness(15, 30, 0, 25);
```

Depois que esta criado a TextBlock eu preciso saber o tamanho atual que ela ficou. Porem o comando `txtMensagem.ActualWidth` retorna 0. Em outro projeto eu fiz a seguinte gambiarra:

```
gridMensagem.Children.Add(txtMensagem);
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
gridMensagem.Children.Remove(txtMensagem);

//Agora o ActualWidth Funciona
double tamanho = txtMensagem.ActualWidth;
```

Esse código eu adiciono na grid, dou o comando 'DoEvents()' para a text ser desenhada na tela e depois eu removo ela, assim eu consigo pegar o tamanho que ela vai ocupar com o comando `txtMensagem.ActualWidth` , porém o mesmo código não funciona nesse meu novo projeto.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de que posso fazer para conseguir o tamanho da TextBlock?

**Obs.: Estou usando WPF**

Grato.

Comment: Veja se [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9264398/2556111) ajuda.

Comment: Cara, quase hehehe... isso me retorna o tamanho do texto(sting), porem no meu caso eu precisaria do tamanho da TextBlock. Mas deu pra fazer uma gambiarra aqui, pois o tamanho da TextBlock sempre vai estar entre 200 e 500, então se voltar menor que 200 eu considero 200 e se voltar maior que 500 eu considero 500 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No link que o ramaral me passou encontrei o seguinte trecho de código que funcionou. Não entendi muito bem como ele funciona mas deu certo.

```
TextBlock txtMensagem = new TextBlock();
txtMensagem.Text = texto.Trim();
txtMensagem.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
txtMensagem.Height = Double.NaN;
txtMensagem.Width = Double.NaN;
txtMensagem.MinWidth = 200;
txtMensagem.MaxWidth = 500;
txtMensagem.FontSize = 16;
txtMensagem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
txtMensagem.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
txtMensagem.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
txtMensagem.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
txtMensagem.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
txtMensagem.Margin = new Thickness(15, 30, 0, 25);

//Codigo retirado do comentário do ramaral
txtMensagem.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
txtMensagem.Arrange(new Rect(txtMensagem.DesiredSize));

//Agora o ActualWidth Funciona
double tamanho = txtMensagem.ActualWidth;
```

Colocando essas duas linhas antes de chamar o ActualWidth funciona.